# How to decode this json data in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```json
{
    "status": "success",
    "errors": null,
    "message": "Records Found successfully.",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "department_id": 1,
            "permissions": "{\"eventStatus\":\"1\",\"dptStatus\":\"1\",\"empStatus\":\"1\",\"policyStatus\":\"1\",\"openingStatus\":\"1\",\"birthdayStatus\":\"1\",\"hrdStatus\":\"1\",\"supportStatus\":\"1\",\"libraryStatus\":\"1\",\"exemptionStatus\":\"1\",\"settingStatus\":\"1\",\"assetsStatus\":\"1\"}"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to convert this json to dart model class?

Answer (score 1):

You either do it on your own, with `jsonDecode()` and `Map`, or use the `json_serializable` package.

### Using `jsonDecode()`

1. deserialize the json with `jsonDecode`: `final jsonMap = jsonDecode(jsonString) as Map<String, dynamic>;`
2. create the class with a constructor that takes in the map

```dart
class ResponseModel {
  final String status;
  // Don't know what this looks like
  final Object errors;
  final String message;
  final DataModel data;

  ResponseModel(this.status, this.errors);

  ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : status = json['status'] as String,
        errors = json['errors'] as Object,
        message = json['message'] as String,
        data = DataModel.fromJson(json['data']);

  // optionally a toJson() as well
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'status': status,
    'errors': errors,
    'message': message,
    'data': data.toJson()
  };
}

class DataModel {
  final String id;
  final int department_id;
  final String permissions;

  DataModel(this.status, this.errors);

  DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'] as String,
        department_id = json['department_id'] as int,
        permissions = json['permissions'] as String

  // optionally a toJson() as well
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'id': id,
    'department_id': department_id,
    'permissions': permissions
  };
}
```

### Using the `json_serializable` package

1. add the dependencies with: `flutter pub add json_annotation dev:build_runner dev:json_serializable`
2. create the class

```dart
class ResponseModel {
  final String status;
  final Object errors;
  // ... rest of the fields

  ResponseModel({required this.status, required this.errors});

  // these two methods will show an error, they will be generated later
  factory ResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ResponseModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ResponseModelToJson(this);
}
```

3. run `build_runner`: `dart run build_runner build`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library to decode:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

It has a method

```
json.decode()
```

This will decode the josnData.

You can also explore [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) website to make a model class.

Comment: Great to hear that you resolved the issue! If you'd like, you can accept the answer, and it will also benefit the community.